# How can I pass a null value to commerce?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I am populating a drop-down with product variants like this:

```
<select name="mySelect" class="form-control">
<option value="">Select</option>
{% for purchasable in product.variants %}
    <option {% if purchasable.stock <= 0 and purchasable.unlimitedStock == false %}disabled {% endif %}
        value="{{ purchasable.purchasableId }}">
            {{ purchasable.myProduct.label }} &ndash; {{ purchasable.price|currency(cart.currency) }}
    </option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

This is not going to be a required field, so its possible a user could submit without making a choice.

The error I currently get is:

```
Not a purchasable ID
```

Which makes complete sense since I am not passing anything to the cart.

Is it best to have a product called "Select" and just have it be zero dollars? Or is there a way - maybe custom plugin - that will skip the input if it has no value?

**EDIT**

Or do I force the user to make a choice of "No thanks" (or whatever is applicable) then that option has a price of zero dollars...

**EDIT 2**

If the user does not make a choice, then Craft gets really angry because I have not passed in a valid purchasable ID (a `null` value).

In the screenshot, the profile is optional. The user doesn't *have* to pick one. If they do, all is well since they have chosen a valid purchasable. The selected default value is `null`.

[image]

**EDIT 3**

Well, I guess for now I take everything back. I've tried several times to break it but I can't today. I haven't changed anything that I can think of, but this seems to be working. If I don't choose anything, I am taken to the `/cart` page as expected.

```
<option value="">Select Profile</option>
    {% for profile in profiles %}
        <option value="{{ profile.defaultVariant.purchasableId }}" data-price="{{ profile.defaultVariant.price|currency(cart.currency) }}">
            {{ profile.title }} &ndash; {% if profile.defaultVariant.price == 0 %} Included with registration {% else %} {{ profile.defaultVariant.price|currency(cart.currency) }}{% endif %}
        </option>
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you tried `value="null"` on the empty option?

Comment: Hi Josh - no luck. Still get a 500 error.

Comment: Perhaps try `false` instead. Shooting in the dark here but it's worth a try! Maybe ask in the commerce channel on Slack as well?

Comment: Absolutely - I appreciate the suggestions!

Comment: "This is not going to be a required field, so its possible a user could submit without making a choice." - How can a user submit the form without a purchasable ID? What does the form do if not adding a product to the cart? (which will require a purchasable ID)

Comment: Hi Luke - I've updated my question with a screen shot to help show what I currently have.

Comment: So from your 3rd edit it looks like you found a solution?

Comment: So far so good - can't say I really found anything. :)
I'll vote to close.